# Combine two arrays in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose we have two arrays:

```
foo = [1, 2] # can be mapped in [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
bar = [{id: 2}, {id: 4}]
```

As a result I need to get following array:

```
res = [ [1, nil], [2, {id: 2}], [nil, {id: 4}] ] 
# Is also ok [ [{id: 1}, nil], [{id: 2}, {id: 2}], [nil, {id: 4}] ]
```

I there any standard Ruby method to get such combinations? At first I'm looking for Ruby way, elegant, short solution.

In other words, I need to get an array diff map, which shows absent and newly added elements.

Comment: Nil in this case indicates absence of element

Comment: @ekremkaraca I'm not sure if the Rails tag should be removed. It might indicate that this is a problem within a Rails application which could expand the list of allowed methods that could be used to solve the problem. For example, `ActiveSupport`s methods.

Comment: @Viktor we should evaluate questions within its scope. it seems there are things that might have relations with activesupport, but not rails itself. it might be updated with rails-specific items, so "rails" tag would not be removed or "activesupport" tag would be replaced.

Comment: IMO the tags must be updated if the OP explicitly agrees with it or there's no doubt such technology isn't involved. Feel free to update the question if that's the case.

Comment: @ekremkaraca I can't agree with that. One might, for example, ask how to check if an object is `nil`, `false` or empty and put the `ruby-on-rails` and `ruby` tags. According to your logic the `rails` tag should be removed because the question "isn't within rails' scope". The answers might explain how to write a method to do that, but the actual answer should just point the OP to the `blank?` method. But the people who answer the question didn't know the problem is within a Rails app because the tag is removed. Trivial example but I think it applies here.

Comment: @Viktor It's better to see updates on the question. I don't want to go further, answers might be related with rails but at this point, the question is not within scope of the "rails".

Comment: Your question isn't asked well. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. We need to see your attempt. Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write code for you, which is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would transform the two arrays to lookup hashes. Then collect all the ids to iterate. Map the ids into the `foo` and `bar` values, then zip them together.

```
foo_lookup = foo.to_h { |id| [id, {id: id}] } # change `{id: id}` into `id` for the other output
bar_lookup = bar.to_h { |item| [item[:id], item] }

ids = foo_lookup.keys | bar_lookup.keys

res = ids.map(&foo_lookup).zip(ids.map(&bar_lookup))
#=> [[{:id=>1}, nil], [{:id=>2}, {:id=>2}], [nil, {:id=>4}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The elements:

```
elements = (foo + bar.map{ |h| h.values.first }).uniq
#=> [1, 2, 4]
```

and the combinations:

```
elements.map { |i| [foo.include?(i) ? i : nil, bar.include?({id: i}) ? {id: i} : nil] }
#=> [[1, nil], [2, {:id=>2}], [nil, {:id=>4}]]
```

Or as Sebastian suggested, you can also use `#find` instead of `#includes?`:

```
elements.map { |i| [foo.find { |e| e == i }, bar.find { |e| e == { id: i } }] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another option.

```
foo = [1, 2]
bar = [{id: 2}, {id: 4}]
(foo + bar).group_by { |e| e.is_a?(Hash) ? e[:id] : e }.values.map { |e| e.size == 1 ? e << nil : e }
#=> [[1, nil], [2, {:id=>2}], [{:id=>4}, nil]]
```

The first part returns

```
(foo + bar).group_by { |e| e.is_a?(Hash) ? e[:id] : e }.values
#=> [[1], [2, {:id=>2}], [{:id=>4}]]
```

If you need to sort the sub arrays, just map using [Array#unshift](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-unshift) or [Array#push](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-push) (prepend or append `nil`) depending in the element already there.